# How to fit an icon in editActionsForRowAt action

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I set an icon in the centre of the action ? 
I'm using this code, which add 3 actions, `colurCode` `Done/Undo` & `Delete` All these when swiped on a cell takes mostly all space of the cell. I want to add custom icon instead of text, but when I add it it doesnt show in my slider, maybe it isnt centred in the action, how can I do that ? :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {


    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        let task = self.tasks[indexPath.row]
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        self.tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        context.delete(task)
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        //tableView.reloadData()

    }

    let colorCode = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Color") { (action, indexPath) in


        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popOver")as! popUpViewController
        self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
        popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
        popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    }



    let cell=tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    if cell.checkTest.on{
        let undone = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Undo") { (action, indexPath) in
            let task = self.tasks[indexPath.row]
            task.checkDone = "off"
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
            // Update Cell
            cell.stopanimate()
            tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
        }
        undone.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "red dot")!)
        return [delete, undone, colorCode]

    }
    else{
        let done = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Done") { (action, indexPath) in
            let task = self.tasks[indexPath.row]
            task.checkDone = "on"
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

            let cell=tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell 
            cell.makeanimate()                
            tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true) 
        } 
        done.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "tick1")!)
        return [delete, done, colorCode]


    }


}
```

Comment: What are the other titles?

Comment: @Joe I edited my question :)

Comment: Consider using an icons instead of title.

Comment: @Joe I used this `delete.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "tick1")!) but It doesnt seem to show up.
`

Comment: @Joe Do you know how it the icon placed in the action, like what size would fit right in ?

Comment: Your post have too many questions after your `edit`.Before,i answer your question from the original post you haven't mentioned about other 2 other actions.?

Comment: See the edited question now.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add some blank space to your `row action title` like this `"      Delete     "`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "      Delete     ") { (action, indexPath) in

}
return [delete]
}
```

Comment: I also have 2 other actions in my row, so all of them take a lot of width. Can I not set a custom width of each ?